# Tensorflow SummaryWriter lost iterations

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am using simple tutorial code from here https://www.oreilly.com/learning/hello-tensorflow

Here is my version:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant(1.0, name='input')
w = tf.Variable(0.8, name='weight')
y = tf.mul(w, x, name='output')
y_ = tf.constant(0.0, name='correct_value')
loss = tf.pow(y - y_, 2, name='loss')
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.025).minimize(loss)
summary_y = tf.scalar_summary('output', loss)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('outs')
for i in range(1000):
  summary_writer.add_summary(sess.run(summary_y), i)
  sess.run(train_step)
```

After, I have only 914 of 1000 steps in tensorboard. Here is an inspection:

```
tensorboard --inspect --logdir=outs

======================================================================
Processing event files... (this can take a few minutes)
======================================================================

Found event files in:
outs

These tags are in outs:
audio -
histograms -
images -
scalars
   output
======================================================================

Event statistics for outs:
audio -
graph -
histograms -
images -
scalars
   first_step           0
   last_step            913
   max_step             913
   min_step             0
   num_steps            914
   outoforder_steps     []
sessionlog:checkpoint -
sessionlog:start -
sessionlog:stop -
======================================================================
```

If I open tensorboard, I see correct plots for 914 steps (from 0 to 913). 
This happens regardless to number of steps. If, for example, I take 100 steps, only 93 are saved in summary.

I am using Fedora 23 (4.6.5-200.fc23.x86_64 GNU/Linux). 
Tensorflow is latest fresh installation within virtual env

```
pip list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow (0.10.0rc0)
```

Any ideas where are last iterations lost?

Answer (score 1):

A [`tf.train.SummaryWriter`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#SummaryWriter) object buffers summaries internally, so it's important to call [`summary_writer.close()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#SummaryWriter.close) before exiting. You can also call [`summary_writer.flush()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#SummaryWriter.flush) to ensure that the most recently written summary has been written to the event log. The following simple modification to your training loop should work:

```
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('outs')
for i in range(1000):
  summary_writer.add_summary(sess.run(summary_y), i)
  sess.run(train_step)
summary_writer.close()
```